# How to have an && condition in a for loop declaration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I would like to write this statement in MATLAB.

```
for c = 1:c1-50 && c1+50:cmax;
```

But I get the following error:-
"Operands to the || and && operators
must be convertible to logical scalar
values."

**Any elegant solution to writing such a statement without using more than one for loop?**

Working code was:-

```
for c = 1:c1-50;
```

and then the second for loop

```
for c = c1+50:cmax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you want to iterate over two different ranges of values. The first range is [1:c1-50], and the second one is [c1+50:cmax].

The proper way for doing so is to concatenate the two ranges together:

```
for c = [1:c1-50, c1+50:cmax]   
%put your code here  
end
```

Two more comments:

1. In MATLAB, [1:c1-50] and [c1+50:max] are two vectors of integers. 
   Performing logical operation between them won't achieve the desired result in your case.
2. When performing logical operation between two arrays of logical's, use only one character of '&' or '|'.